# Select Entire Single Group using Bootstrap Multiselect (optgroups)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I would like to have a drop down list that upon selecting a group, all the items in that group are selected/displayed. I do not want the option of selecting only part of the group. And I do not want the option of selecting more than one group

Additionally, I want to be able to search for a group by searching for one of its members

I am using Bootstrap multiselect (https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

[image: multiselect]

This is what I currently have:

```
 <select id="family-select" class="form-control" multiple>
            <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
                <option value="1-2">Option 1.2</option>
                <option value="1-3">Option 1.3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 2">
                <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>



      $('#family-select').multiselect({
        enableClickableOptGroups: true,
        enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        buttonClass: 'btn btn-link',
        disableIfEmpty: true,
    });
```